# Ruby isn't a PHP generator, right?

Tags: php, ruby

My boss was looking down on me about learning Ruby because "It's just a PHP generator" which I can't find anything about it being so. Is this the case?

I understand that the Rails framework can be used to generate PHP code, but isn't Ruby in-and-of-itself its own programming language?

Comment: Rails generates PHP code? Really? I wouldn't know, I'm not even a Ruby guy, much less a Rails guy, but it seems completely pointless and *way* too complicated (both to do and to get right).

Comment: Perl influenced both PHP and Ruby, other than that, I don't see the two being related outside of similar problem domains.

Comment: I sympathize with your plight there, but this seems like a question that could've been answered with just a little bit of research. This feels off-topic to me for this site.

Comment: @Anna I did research and found nothing to say yay or nay `which I can't find anything about it being so`. so I asked.

Comment: I'm sorry, but [really](http://www.google.ca/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=is+ruby+a+programming+language)? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)) in particular seems to be fairly comprehensive and proves that Ruby is its own language.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I get that it's a softball question, but it isn't that hard for us to answer with a yes or no including a link for more info. At least some thoughtful responders got in before the question was slapped down.

Comment: THIS IS A REAL QUESTION!  The Question Nazis are ruining StackExchange.

Comment: ANSWER: Your boss probably read [this](http://eric_rollins.home.mindspring.com/pgen/index.html) or [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/generating-php-with-ruby/) or *maybe* (but not likely) [this](http://php.rubyforge.org/) and was making a snide know-it-all comment on Ruby only being useful for this one thing.

Comment: @iconoclast If you knew Anna lear's contribution, you would not call her a "Question Nazi". Beside, all this moderation effort is what keeps stackexchange relevant.

Comment: Her contribution is irrelevant.  The only thing relevant is whether this is a real question, AND IT IS.  Also, pointing out the importance of moderation is a red herring.  Of course we need moderation, but we need GOOD moderation, not careless abuse of power.

Comment: Ruby on Rails is used to generate HTML & handle HTTP requests, not write PHP.  I think somebody doesn't really understand what's going on & is just using terms similar to what they already understand.

Answer (score 21):

Dilbert's principle in action.

No, ruby isn't a PHP generator. It is a language that has nothing to do with PHP except some usages.

Comment: LOL i have a funnier addition for you: she's the owner and CEO o.0

Comment: The higher up they are, the more Dilbert's principle applies.

Comment: @mechaflash let me guess: it's a small shop, and it pretends to be a corporate-thingie.

Answer (score 7):

[Ruby is a full-fledged language.](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/)

As far as the statement made by your boss is concerned, if Ruby is "just a PHP generator," then so is C, Java, C#, Clojure, etc.

Ruby is a good language because it you can express things in the [Functional Paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (for example, Ruby has lambdas).

Learn Ruby.  It will change how you see problems.:)

Comment: PHP now have lambda and closure. In a far futur, his boos may be right ! We are all DOOOOOOMED !

Comment: I wasn't aware that PHP had closures or lamdbas.  Thanks for the tip.:)

Comment: It is new in PHP5.3 . PHP didn't had this feature before.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** Ruby is in-and-of-itself its own programming language

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/

> Ruby is...
>
> A dynamic, open source programming language with a focus on simplicity and productivity.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that the Rails framework can be used to generate PHP code

That's not generally true. I suppose somebody somewhere may have made this happen, but their mental health problems would not be insignificant.

In general, Rails applications are written in a mixture of languages underpinned by Ruby, the others including HTML, CSS, Javascript. While HTML may be replaced by, for example, [HAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml), and Javascript (recently) by [Coffeescript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript), with compilation steps occurring as needed, I've never seen Ruby being "compiled" down to PHP.

Ruby and PHP both appeared at about the same time, according to Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)). Ruby was a fairly general-purpose scripting language that erupted into the Web World with the advent of Rails in 2004, whereas AFAIK, PHP was designed for web development.

Comment: Someone actually did make this (well, Ruby to PHP, anyway) happen. Fructose generator: http://fructoselang.org/

Answer (score 1):

One point nobody has mentioned - if Ruby *were* a PHP generator (spoiler alert - it's not), who cares?  C is "just an assembly generator", so I guess we should look down on people who learn C.

Comment: The sad thing is that people used to do that for a long time.

Comment: I guess the differentiatior here is that (at least, to me) ruby and php occupy a space on the same level of abstraction from the machine, which _would_ be redundant.

Comment: @SnOrfus - I think we should all have a think about CoffeeScript now. ;)

Comment: nonsense, my processor runs C directly!